# Has DriveApp folder.getUrl() changed or broken?

Tags: google-apps-script

The following function returns null values for url
function test() {

```
    var folderiter = DriveApp.getFolders();
          while (folderiter.hasNext()) {
          var  folder = folderiter.next();
          Logger.log(folder.getName()+" url:"+folder.getUrl())


  }
```

}

Comment: Issue http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's broken, as DavidF said, but here's a workaround:

```
function myFunction() {

  var folderiter = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (folderiter.hasNext()) {
            var  folder = folderiter.next()
            var  folderId = folder.getId()//new line added to your code
            //DocsList.getFolderById(folderId).getURL() works to get url as variable
            var  url = DocsList.getFolderById(folderId).getUrl()
            Logger.log(folder.getName()+" url:"+url)//modified to use variable instead of method


  }

}
```

I did test this with my own folders and files, but I can't confirm it works with every file/folder type.  However, if it helps you, can you accept the answer?

Comment: The prob was fixed a few hours after issue raised

Comment: Oh. I tested this with another answer right before I posted it on that one, and it was still an issue. I guess it got resolved as I was finishing and browsing around. Thanks for the update.

Comment: The bug has returned! While the DocsList workaround is fine it more than doubles the execution time - I suggest forming the url for folder directly by prefixing the ID with "https://docs.google.com/a/YOURDOMAINNAME/open?id="