# Google scripts, get a drive file url

Tags: google-apps-script, geturl

I need my script to load the URL of a drive file to be added to a spreadsheet. For whatever reason 'File.getUrl()' returns null, but everything else seems to be working.

For example, 'File.getName()' works. So am I missing a permission or something?

Here is my code (abridged):

```
function loadURL(folderPath, name) {       
  var folder = loadFolder(folderPath);

  // Find file
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate >= "' + getDate() + '" and title = "' + name + '"'),
      file, found = 0;

  for (; files.hasNext(); found++) {
    file = files.next();
  }

  if (found == 1) {
    /////////////////////////////////
    // Here is 'getUrl'
    /////////////////////////////////
    var url = file.getUrl();

    Logger.log("Loaded: " + url);
    return url;
  } else {
    throw "Error loading file";
  }
}

/**
* ** NOTE: THIS SEEMS TO BE WORKING FINE **
* Load a folder
* @param {string} url
* @return {Folder}
*/
function loadFolder(url) {
  var folders = url.split('/'),
      folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

  Logger.log("Loading URL: " + url);

  for (var key in folders) {
    var fName = folders[key];    
    if (fName.length > 0) {
      var fIt = folder.getFoldersByName(fName),
          found = 0;

      Logger.log(" -> " + fName);

      for (; fIt.hasNext(); found++) {
        folder = fIt.next();
      }

      if (found == 0) {
        throw "Could not find the folder '" + fName + "'";
      } else if (found > 1) {
        throw "Found multiple matches to the folder '" + fName + "'";
      }
    }
  }

  return folder;
}
```

And the log if you're curious:

```
[14-02-26 19:56:15:980 EST] Loading URL: Work/PDF/
[14-02-26 19:56:15:981 EST]  -> Work
[14-02-26 19:56:16:120 EST]  -> PDF
[14-02-26 19:56:16:450 EST] Loaded: null
```

And if I change getUrl to getName it (kinda) works

```
[14-02-26 20:10:20:588 EST] Loading URL: Work/PDF/
[14-02-26 20:10:20:589 EST]  -> Work
[14-02-26 20:10:20:727 EST]  -> PDF
[14-02-26 20:10:21:058 EST] Loaded: Test
```

Comment: same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055396/has-driveapp-folder-geturl-changed-or-broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var url = DocsList.getFileById(fileId).getUrl();
```

Was recommended as a workaround by a poster on the issue thread that zig posted.

So, in your case, you'd use:

```
  for (; files.hasNext(); found++) {
    file = files.next();
  }

  if (found == 1) {
    /////////////////////////////////
    // Here is 'getUrl'
    /////////////////////////////////
    var fileId = file.getId();//new line added to getId of the file

    //modified url line to reference doc by id
    var url = DocsList.getFileById(fileId).getUrl();

    Logger.log("Loaded: " + url);
    return url;
  } else {
    throw "Error loading file";
  }
```

I didn't get to test this right now because it's late and I'd have to build a the right structure to test it properly, but since you already have the structure change those two commented lines and let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using the id instead of the url works:

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + file.getId() + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Today started an issue with drive getUrl, google is aware of it and working on it.
Does work using docList or drive advanced services.

Comment: I am still having issues with images from drive.

Exception: Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IJpu....YbxdEmQI&export=download